# How to style the date input placeholder for Contact Form 7

Tags: html, css, contact-form-7

How do I change the dd/mm/yyyy placeholder of a date input, and have a different color text once a date is selected?

I have tried the following code to no avail:

```
input[type="date"] {
    color: pink;
}

::-webkit-datetime-edit-day-field[aria-valuetext=blank],
::-webkit-datetime-edit-month-field[aria-valuetext=blank],
::-webkit-datetime-edit-year-field[aria-valuetext=blank] {
  color: gren;
}
```

And

```
input[type="date"] {
    color: pink;
}

::-webkit-datetime-edit-day-field:not([aria-valuetext]),
::-webkit-datetime-edit-month-field:not([aria-valuetext]),
::-webkit-datetime-edit-year-field:not([aria-valuetext]) 
{
  color: green;
}
```

And

```
input[type="date"] {
    color: pink;
}

input[type="date"]:invalid::-webkit-datetime-edit-text,
input[type="date"]:invalid::-webkit-datetime-edit-day-field,
input[type="date"]:invalid::-webkit-datetime-edit-month-field,
input[type="date"]:invalid::-webkit-datetime-edit-year-field {
  color: green;
}
```

HTML

```
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap date-457">
    <input type="date" name="date-457" value="" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-date wpcf7-validates-as-date" aria-invalid="false">
</span>
```

None of these styles work for altering the placeholder and having the selected date a different color. I imagine these solutions are outdated as I cannot find any answers on here relating to 2017-2018.

Comment: I cannot alter the HTML as it is CF7.

Comment: @DanielVickers I think you are able to use [HTML in the Form  section](https://blog.cf7skins.com/styling-contact-form-7-forms/#finalcsschanges#html) and it will be converted.

Comment: @zer00ne this post does not mention styling date fields nor does any article I have found. Thanks though :)

Comment: @DanielVickers That comment was in regards to your ability to change HTML to which you said, *"I cannot alter the HTML as it is CF7"*. Apparently you can alter HTML via the Form section. Do you agree?

Comment: Debatable, you add html to a form of course. But the question stands at how to style the date field and is not with regards to passing HTML. I mean using the shortcode I cannot alter the HTML output of CF7. Of course I could type it out...

Comment: target placeholder text with ::placeholder. "The ::placeholder CSS pseudo-element represents the placeholder text of a form element." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::placeholder

Comment: Does not work @CarolMcKay it does not style input types of dates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to do this, but it needs that you add the `required` attribute to the `input`. Then, you can use the [:valid](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:valid) and [:invalid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:invalid) **pseudo-selectors** for style the input when his value have or not a valid format. Check next examples, the first one just make text **green** when a date is selected, otherwise the text keep **black**:

```css
input[type="date"]:valid {
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap date-457">
    <input type="date" name="date-457" value="" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-date wpcf7-validates-as-date" aria-invalid="false" required>
</span>
```

This next one, is similar to previous, but adds a **red** text when date is invalid and we hover over the input.

```css
input[type="date"]:valid {
    color: green;
}

input[type="date"]:invalid:hover {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap date-457">
    <input type="date" name="date-457" value="" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-date wpcf7-validates-as-date" aria-invalid="false" required>
</span>
```

The last alternative (not CSS only), using **JQuery** (and without the required attribute) is using a listener on the `input` event and check the value in order to manipulate the style of the input:

```js
$("input[type='date']").on('input', function()
{
    $(this).css("color", "red");
    
    if ($(this).val())
        $(this).css("color", "green");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap date-457">
    <input type="date" name="date-457" value="" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-date wpcf7-validates-as-date" aria-invalid="false">
</span>
```

Comment: But this automatically sets the default value to pink (error color). Shouldn't it be the default color, and if all fields selected, then green. And if cancelled, then 'pink' to highlight the error?

Comment: So, you want default (initial) value to **black**, when invalid (cancelled) **pink** color and when a valid date selected **green** color? Sorry, but i'm not fully understanding your goals, if you can explain in details, I will adapt my code.

Comment: Just removed the default **pink** color. Observation **1)** From **chrome** browser I can't remove a date once a date is selected (when required is specified), so once the text has changed to **green** it will keep that way. **2)** Check the [Date Field Options](https://contactform7.com/date-field/), there is a placeholder option that can replace the default value. Maybe using this option plus the **:valid**, **:invalid** pseudo-selector you can approach your style. Unfortunately, i don't have a way to do the testing with this framework you are using.

Answer (score 2):

From your question, I understand that you want to change the color of the date once it is selected. I am suggesting to use JQuery, however I do understand you only tagged CSS.

You can easily achieve what you wanted by using JQuery method `change()`. I've also added an ID for your date field so that we can use `getElementById` to change the CSS when the date is set.

Also, when you click the cancel button, the date color can be changed to another color or go back to its original. In this example, I set it to red.

The idea is that when the date field is NOT empty, it will show green color. And when the date is empty, it will show another color (in this example is red, you can choose to set it back to original color.  I did this so that you can see the green when not empty and red when empty).

So when the field is not empty, it means the length is > 0. Using that idea, we can set that when the date field is not empty, we change it to green and when its empty, we change it to red.

Try this:

```js
$('#date').change(function()
{
      if( $(this).val().length > 0 ) {
        document.getElementById("date").style.color = "green";  
    } else {
     document.getElementById("date").style.color = "red";
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap date-457">
    <input type="date" name="date-457" value="" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-date wpcf7-validates-as-date" aria-invalid="false" id="date">
</span>
```

ps: If you don't want the answer in JQuery, let me know and I'll delete this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You want to change color when selecting date.It that right! I understand like that. You can check on chrome.

```css
input[type="date"] {
    color: pink;
}
::-webkit-datetime-edit-month-field:focus,::-webkit-datetime-edit-day-field:focus,::-webkit-datetime-edit-year-field:focus {
    color:green;
    background:transparent;
}
```

```html
<input type="date" name="date-457" value="" aria-invalid="false">
```

Comment: This does not work as it is on focus, it should be 1 colour before selecting a date. And a different colour permanently once a date has been selected.